# Repeating a std::string n times

Tags: c++, performance, strings

I recently posted an answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166630/how-to-repeat-a-string-a-variable-number-of-times-in-c/34321702#34321702) as I did not think any of the current answers were satisfactory (most don't even answer the question!). I was wondering if anyone could offer any improvements on my solution to this problem? I'm most interested in performance here. Also note this algorithm does not require any additional copies of the input string (if passed an r-value), ideally I'd like to keep this property.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>  // std::size_t
#include <cmath>    // std::floor, std::log2, std::pow
#include <iterator> // std::cbegin, std::cend, std::next

std::string repeatstring(std::string str, std::size_t n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        str.clear();
        str.shrink_to_fit();
        return str;
    }

    if (n == 1 || str.empty()) return str;

    const auto repeat_size = str.size();

    if (repeat_size == 1) {
        str.append(n - 1, str.front());
        return str;
    }

    str.reserve(repeat_size * n);

    const auto m = static_cast<decltype(n)>(std::floor(std::log2(n)));

    for (auto i = m; i > 0; --i) str += str;

    n -= static_cast<decltype(n)>(std::pow(2, m));

    str.append(std::cbegin(str), std::next(std::cbegin(str), n * repeat_size));

    return str;
}
```

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto str = repeatstring("helloworld", 190238011);

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    //std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "string length: " << str.length() << std::endl;

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);

    std::cout << "time: " << duration.count() << "ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 7):

**Input as reference-to-const**

Change your signature to:

```
std::string repeat_string(std::string const& str, std::size_t N);
```

First, this avoids an unnecessary copy when users *don't* pass their strings in by rvalue (which seems more typical?). Secondly, this allows for copy elision on the returned object, as you can't have copy elision from a function parameter. So if I called `repeat_string` with an lvalue, I just saved two copies.

Also, note the name change. Either use `camelCase` or `snake_case` or function names, don't just `jamlotsofwordstogether`. It's much harder to read.

The new signature makes some of the other code easier.

```
if (n == 0) {
    return {};
}

...

if (str.size() == 1) {
    return std::string(n str[0]);
}
```

**`repeat_size`**

This is a weird variable at best. Once you make `str` a reference to const, you can just access `str.size()` which makes much more sense. `repeat_size` isn't really the size of the repeat - that's what `n` is...

**Powers of 2**

`std::log2` and `std::pow` aren't cheap, and you need neither. For the former, you can just multiply by two until you're done:

```
std::string result = str;
result.reserve(str.size() * n);

std::size_t m = 2;
for (; m <= n; m *= 2)
{
    result += result;
}
```

Now `m` is the first power of 2 larger than `n`. So you can replace

```
n -= static_cast<decltype(n)>(std::pow(2, m));
```

with:

```
n -= m/2;
```

And:

```
str.append(std::cbegin(str), std::next(std::cbegin(str), n * repeat_size));
```

is a really complicated way of writing what now becomes:

```
result.append(result.c_str(), n * str.size());
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with all these points. You only save 1 copy in the case that `n == 0` when passing by const reference. Correct me if I'm wrong, but `str` is guaranteed to be moved out of the function (if RVO is not applied). I think the benefit of not forcing  a copy when `n != 0` is preferable.

Comment: @Daniel Did you time it? You're looping anyway.

Comment: no, you're probably right actually, but little point trying to measure the difference given the runtime of this function will be completely dominated by the copying.

Comment: Can I ask where you have seen that copy elision isn't allowed on function parameters? I was just reading [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12953150/2970186) and the author mentions pass by value as a common form of copy elision.

Comment: @Daniel It's the copy *into* the function that's elided, not the copy out of.

Comment: @Daniel From the standard: "copy elision [...] is permitted [...] in a return statement [...]  (other than a function parameter or a variable introduced by the exception-declaration of a handler (15.3))"

Answer (score 5):

```
n -= static_cast<decltype(n)>(std::pow(2, m));
```

can be replaced with

```
n -= 1 << m;
```

`<< m` essentially means multiply by 2 to the power of `m`

Similarly you can get `m` by finding the highest set bit. For which most compilers will [provide an intrinsic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671815/731620) which will do this much faster than it could provide the log2 of the number.

Comment: I think you actually want to shift a `std::size_t` value of `1` rather than a (signed) `int` there.

Answer (score 0):

There's very little benefit in writing `decltype(n)` when we know that type is `std::size_t` - just write the known type.  `decltype` has its place, but that's normally in templates or where the type is difficult or impossible to write (usually when deduced using `auto`).

Of course, that's irrelevant once you apply the suggested improvement that removes the need for `<cmath>` and the casts.